# Convert timestamp in video description to link

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a page where users can add a video description. I want to be able to identify timestamps in the description similar to how YouTube does. From what I have seen, writing a regular expression is the best way to find these timestamps. Currently my script does not work.

```
function timestampify(text) {
    return text.replace(/\d+$/, '', '<a data-time="$1" class="timestamp-link">$1</a>')
}
/*
Music used:
0:00 - Rhythm Heaven - Rhythm Calligraphy
1:46 - Mario Party 6 - Night at the Garage
3:00 - POKEMON: Super Mystery Dungeon - Onward, Expedition Society!
36:10 - Mario Party 9 - DK's Jungle Ruins
47:23 - Rhythm Heaven - Rhythm Calligraphy
01:03:23 - Rhythm Heaven Fever: Prologues - Power Calligraphy Prologue
*/
```

Comment: Maybe `return text.replace(/^\d+(?::\d+)+/gm, '<a data-time="$&" class="timestamp-link">$&</a>')` will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the value represents time, I would use something like this:

```
/^[0-5]?\d(?::[0-5]?\d){1,2}/gm
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wjBbrY/1).

**Breakdown:**

```
^             # The beginning of the string/line.
[0-5]?        # And optional number between 0 and 5.
\d            # Any digit.
(?:           # The start of a non-capturing group.
    :         # Matches the character ":" literally.
    [0-5]?\d  # Any digit, optionally preceded by a number between 0 and 5.
)             # The end of the non-capturing group.
{1,2}         # Match between one and two times of the previous group (`ss` or `mm:ss`).
```

**JavaScript example:**

```js
function timestampify(text) {
    return text.replace(/^[0-5]?\d(?::[0-5]?\d){1,2}/gm, '<a data-time="$&" class="timestamp-link">$&</a>')
}

var text = `
0:00 - Rhythm Heaven - Rhythm Calligraphy
1:46 - Mario Party 6 - Night at the Garage
3:00 - POKEMON: Super Mystery Dungeon - Onward, Expedition Society!
36:10 - Mario Party 9 - DK's Jungle Ruins
47:23 - Rhythm Heaven - Rhythm Calligraphy
01:03:23 - Rhythm Heaven Fever: Prologues - Power Calligraphy Prologue
`

console.log(timestampify(text))
```

Comment: Using your expression I am not getting any matches: https://regex101.com/r/o0ltby/1

Comment: @FunkyKong My bad! I forgot to add the flags (`g` and `m`) in the JavaScript snippet. Fixed. Here: https://regex101.com/r/7MjTSR/1

Answer (score -1):

If we'd not be validating our timestamps, maybe this expression might simply work:

```
\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)\s+
```

which is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fWP5Y5/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/fWP5Y5/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

```js
const regex = /\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)\s+/gm;
const str = `0:00 - Rhythm Heaven - Rhythm Calligraphy
11:46 - Mario Party 6 - Night at the Garage
23:00 - POKEMON: Super Mystery Dungeon - Onward, Expedition Society!
  36:10 - Mario Party 9 - DK's Jungle Ruins
47:23 - Rhythm Heaven - Rhythm Calligraphy
01:03:23 - Rhythm Heaven Fever: Prologues - Power Calligraphy Prologue
   01:03:23 - Rhythm Heaven Fever: Prologues - Power Calligraphy Prologue`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Regex does not match if the minutes column does not have two digits. I should have shown that as a possible situation in my example: https://regex101.com/r/yPPGwU/1